# Ajax use in laravel 5.3

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, forms, laravel-5

I am in a bit of I a fix. I am trying to submit a form using Ajax. Now when I do this without creating the `laravel` default `auth scaffold` it works fine, but if add the `auth scaffold` it fails. I have tried all I can but can't seem to get it to submit.

Here is my code:
controller to send mail --

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Input;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Redirect;

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Response;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Mail;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Validator;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class MailController extends Controller
{
    //
    public function index(Request $request)
      {


          if ($request->ajax()) {
              $validator = Validator::make($request->all(), [
                          'first_name' => 'required',
                          'last_name' => 'required',
                          'email' => 'required|email',
                          'mymessage' => 'required',
                          'g-recaptcha-response' => 'required|captcha',
              ]);

              if ($validator->fails()) {
                  return redirect()->back()
                                  ->withErrors($validator)
                                  ->withInput();
              } else {

                  // get input fields values
                  $data = [
                      'firstName' => $request->input('first_name'),
                      'lastName' => $request->input('last_name'),
                      'email' => $request->input('email'),
                      'mymessage' => $request->input('mymessage'),
                  ];

                  Mail::send('emails.email', $data, function ($message) {
                     official email
                      $message->to('xxxxxxxxx@gmail.com', 'My Name')->subject('Information');
                  });

                  return response()->json([
                              'responseText' => 'Mail was sent!'], 200);
              }
          } else {
              return View('fail')->render();
          }
      }
}
```

The Route files:

```
Route::get('/', function () {
    return view('welcome');
});

Route::post('/mail', [
    'as' => 'mail',
    'uses' => 'MailController@index'
]);

Auth::routes();

Route::get('/home', 'HomeController@index');
```

Ajax code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    var options = {
        beforeSubmit: validate,
        url: '/mail',
        data: $(this).serialize(),
        type: 'POST',
        dataType: 'json',
        clearForm: true,
        success: great,
        error: lost
    };

    $('#footer-form').ajaxForm(options);
});

function validate(formData, jgForm, options) {
    for (var i = 0; i < formData.length; i++) {
        if (!formData[i].value) {
            alert('Please enter a value for all fields');
            return false;
        }
    }
}

function great(responseText, statusText, formData) {
    // prevent multiple form submission
    $('#mail_btn').prop('disabled', true);
    // show alert on success
    $(".alert-success").prop("hidden", false);
    // remove mail error information if displayed
    $(".alert-info").prop("hidden", true);
    // reset google recaptcha
    grecaptcha.reset();

}

function lost(formData) {
    // prevent multiple form submission
    $('#mail_btn').prop('disabled', false);
    $(".alert-info").prop("hidden", false);
}
```

My form code:

```
<div class="col-sm-6">
 <div class="footer-content" id="myfooter">
    {!! Form::open(['action' => 'MailController@index', 'method' => 'post', 'role' => 'form', 'id' => 'footer-form']) !!}
                        <div class="form-group has-feedback">
                            {!! Form::label('first_name', null, ['class' => 'sr-only']) !!}
                            {!! Form::text('first_name', null, ['class' => 'form-control', 'placeholder' => 'First Name']) !!}
                            <i class="fa fa-user form-control-feedback"></i>
                            @if($errors->has('first_name'))
                                {{ $errors->first('first_name') }}
                            @endif
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group has-feedback">
                            {!! Form::label('last_name', null, ['class' => 'sr-only']) !!}
                            {!! Form::text('last_name', null, ['class' => 'form-control', 'placeholder' => 'Last Name']) !!}
                            <i class="fa fa-user form-control-feedback"></i>
                            @if($errors->has('last_name'))
                                {{ $errors->first('last_name') }}
                            @endif
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group has-feedback">
                            {!! Form::label('email', null, ['class' => 'sr-only']) !!}
                            {!! Form::email('email', null, ['class' => 'form-control', 'placeholder' => 'Email address']) !!}
                            <i class="fa fa-envelope form-control-feedback"></i>
                            @if($errors->has('email'))
                                {{ $errors->first('email') }}
                            @endif
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group has-feedback">
                            {!! Form::label('mymessage', null, ['class' => 'sr-only']) !!}
                            {!! Form::textarea('mymessage', null, ['class' => 'form-control', 'rows' => 8, 'cols' => 3, 'placeholder' => 'Message']) !!}
                            <i class="fa fa-pencil form-control-feedback"></i>
                            @if($errors->has('mymessage'))
                                {{ $errors->first('mymessage') }}
                            @endif
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group has-feedback">
                            {!! app('captcha')->display() !!}
                        </div>

                        {!! Form::submit('Send', ['class' => 'btn btn-default', 'id' => 'mail_btn']) !!}

                        {!! Form::close() !!}
                        <div class="alert alert-success" id="mail_alert" role="alert" hidden>
                            Mail Sent!
                        </div>
                         <div class="alert alert-info" id="mail_info" role="alert" hidden>
                            Mail Sending Error!
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
```

Error message:

```
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 401 (Unauthorized)
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that I was using `mailgun sandbox account` hence I was only able to send mail when I use the `laravel app` with the `auth scaffold` include with the `auth scaffold` the app would allow as `mailgun sandbox account` don't send any reponse.

Solution was to use regular `gmail` send it and it responded as expected and the mail went through.